# Can we develop iPhone Apps without MacOS License

Tags: cocoa, ios4

I actually want to start iPhone development but don't have license of MacOS. My Question is,

> Is there some other way to start development for iPhone i.e. on Windows, Linux etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible to write the code on a none-apple computer.
I do think, tho, that apple require you to build on a apple machine when building for iPhone/iPad etc.

You will also need a developer license, which I think cost ~$99/year.
Check out the apple dev page for more info!
https://developer.apple.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are free to develop in XCode without a license. However, to publish your app into the App Store, and accessing heaps of information in the Apple Dev Center, you need a license.

Comment: Unfortunately not legally. You might want to take a look at Adobe Air.